# eval calling lambda don't see self

Tags: python

Here is a simple code illustrating the essence of a problem:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 0
    def set(self, val):
        self.var = val
        print eval('map(lambda x: self.var*x, [1,2,3,4,5])')
f = test()
f.set(10)
```

It says

```
NameError: global name 'self' is not defined
```

I know many people don't like eval but in my case I have to use it because it executes a math formula from the string entered by a user during programm execution.
Any suggestions is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: "A math formula" like `__import__("os").system("rm -rf /")`?

Comment: @dan04: There must be a bug in your formula. It's not working on Windows :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
eval('map(lambda x, self=self: self.var*x, [1,2,3,4,5])')
```

The odd `self=self` will create a copy of `self` from the outer context into the inner context (the "body" of the lambda expression).

Comment: Good solution! Thats what I was looking for! :) Thank yo very much!

Comment: @aliko if the answer solves your problem, you should accept it (the 'V' mark below the votes count on the left).

Comment: I wish I could mark all the messages here as accepted but unfortunateley I can mark only one...( Let it be the first correct answer :)

Answer (score 8):

This is a tricky situation. First of all as workaround you can use:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 0
    def set(self, val):
        self.var = val
        print eval('map(lambda x,self=self: self.var*x, [1,2,3,4,5])')
f = test()
f.set(10)
```

The reason is not simple to explain... but let's try.

When you write

```
 lambda x: self.var * x
```

what is created is a "closure", that will capture the current variable "self" as a non-local variable in the lambda expression because self is a local variable in the current environment.

When this lambda is built by `eval` however this local variable `self` is not visible inside `eval` and therefore the lambda function generated will refer to the **global** variable `self` that doesn't exist in this case.

Comment: I did not expected to receive such a helpfull answers within couple of minutes. And yours one is most fundamental... ) It's a great place to ask!:)

Comment: You received helpful answers because you stated your problem clearly, in a simplified form, explained why you wanted to do what you were doing, and because the problem was interesting. If all of your questions are like that, you will keep getting good responses.

Comment: Also, if you didn't know already, when you have decided which answer is the best solution to your problem, there is a small checkmark below the number and arrows which will allow you to mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 7):

Eval() also supports setting global and local variables respectively so you could do something like this:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 0
    def set(self, val):
        self.var = val
        print eval('map(lambda x: self.var*x, [1,2,3,4,5])', dict(globals().items() + [('self', self)]))
f = test()
f.set(10)
```

**Update:** The above example now maintains previous global and local variables.

Comment: The only disadvantage of this approach is that it hides globals from eval.

Comment: @aliko Thank you, you're correct. I've updated my example to maintain the previous globals.

Comment: This solution has the advantage of not having to change the lambda signature, nice.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm sure there is a way to do this without eval, have you tried using string formatting?

```
eval('map(lambda x: %s*x, [1,2,3,4,5])'%self.var)
```

Comment: And this approach is working one! Python is all about choices :)

Answer (score 0):

The more generic answer is to **pass local variables into the eval environment**

The [eval function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) supports two additional parameters, the global and locals variables. So, for instance, you can solve the issue without altering the function by passing:

```
eval(map(lambda x: self.var*x + myvar, [1,2,3,4,5]), dict(self=self, myvar=123))
```